# "В случае", нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В случае Вашего несогласия с изменениями Вы можете прекратить пользоваться Веб-сайтом

Comment: По стилю — официальный ответ, по смыслу — хамство ("не нравится — не покупай"). Или это из раздела "советы потребителю": бойкотируйте сайт, который  вам не нравится?

Answer (score 2):

Обособление оборота с производным предлогом В СЛУЧАЕ является **факультативным.** Этот оборот часто применяется в деловой речи и обычно не обособляется.

Обособление возможно для распространенных оборотов; кроме того,  можно предположить, что  на решение задачи влияет расстановка логических ударений в предложении.

**Пример с обособлением:**

В случае досрОчного расторжения настоящего договора, Исполнитель вправе аннулировать полученную Заказчиком визу без возврата средств... [Договор о туристических услугах (2003)]

Если выделить ударением слово ***досрочного***, то в предложении делается пауза, которая обозначается запятой.

В приведенном примере возможны оба варианта:

(1) В случае Вашего **несоглАсия** с изменениями, Вы можете прекратить пользоваться Веб-сайтом (перенос ударения).

(2) В случае Вашего несогласия **с изменЕниями** Вы можете прекратить пользоваться Веб-сайтом (обычное ударение в конце оборота, а также первой части предложения).